# vs code git error: Git: /usr/bin/bash: init: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

EDIT: I've rebooted my computer, and the issue is fixed. I have no idea why it fixed it.

In vs code on windows, when I try to Initialize Repository, I get the error

[image]

However, it used to worked fine. It changed when I tried to install Ubuntu on Windows following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzgwDbe7foQ&t=690s). Git is installed, and the path is in the .json file. [image][image][image]

Comment: Do you have an alias for "git" or something? Somehow the alias isn't working (is null) and the "git" is effectively being stripped from your command?

Comment: If I have an alias, then why is the git command working in the terminal as shown in one of the screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you to install git in ubuntu by apt

Comment: I removed Ubuntu after I got this problem to see if it would fix but it didnt. I'm not sure if I should reinstall it.

Comment: I think set git.path project settings not global settings. project setting is .vscode/settings.json in   workspace folder.

Answer (score 0):

The `git.path` you've specified is to bash, not git.  There's probably some wrapper that invokes that binary using `git`, and so when you type `git init`, you're really invoking `bash init`, which asks bash to run the script named `init`.  Since it doesn't exist, your command is failing.

You should set `git.path` to a path to a Git binary, and not a bash binary.